# How execute a oncomplete script for many divs based on class selector?

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I've a webpage that uses Ractive js & tries to execute a script for element's with a particular class. Please find the below sample:

```
<body>
<div class='container'></div>
<div class='container'>Hello</div>
<script>
    var ractive = new Ractive({
      // The `el` option can be a node, an ID, or a CSS selector.
      el: '.container',

      oncomplete: function () {
       console.log("22");
      }
    });
</script>
</body>
```

For the above code, I can see only one entry in the console. Why is this the case? How do I get ractive to execute the oncomplete script for all elements having container as class?

Comment: probably because the DOM is already (mostly) established once the script runs - place it into HEAD to have it prepped /before/ the BODY gets populated.

Comment: Could you maybe reproduce this on jsfiddle?

Comment: @flowtron - placing the script in the head doesn't help.In fact it doesn't log anything to the console when placed in the head tag.

Comment: @MartinGottweis https://jsfiddle.net/7yxnd5wb/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't really initiate Ractive with multiple elements. The idea is that you initialize Ractive on the wrapper and then you build up your page with partials.

If you for some reason want to do what you are proposing, you can create multiple Ractive instances on one page like this: http://jsfiddle.net/7yxnd5wb/1/

```
var ractive = new Ractive({
    // The `el` option can be a node, an ID, or a CSS selector.
    el: '.c1',
    template: 'rendered 1',
    onrender: function () {
        console.log("11");
    }
})

var ractive = new Ractive({
    // The `el` option can be a node, an ID, or a CSS selector.
    el: '.c2',
    template: 'rendered 2',
    onrender: function () {
        console.log("22");
    }
})
```

I believe the option to use css class selector is a new one and might be confusing. Most people seem to be using ids for this use.

If you really want to create many ractive instances based on class, consider this function: http://jsfiddle.net/7yxnd5wb/2/

```
function ractive_class (class_selector) {
    return $('.' + class_selector)
        .toArray()
        .map(function (element) {
            return new Ractive({
                el: element,
                template: 'rendered',
                onrender: function () {
                    console.log("rendered");
                }
            }
        )
    })
}

console.log(ractive_class('c'))
```

Comment: Having a new instance for every container is one way. But, I want to be able to write the code with no redundancy.

Comment: I guess you can wrap the ractive creation in a function and apply it to all elements with given class. Added this to the answer including jsfiddle. The function will return an array of ractive instances.